# TimeOut Setting while Accessing .net Web Service

Tags: .net, web-services, java-me, stub

I have developed a Mobile Application for E5 Mobile, Here in my Application I am using .net Web Services for login & other activity. I have created stubs accordingly. My Application is running fine.

Now My Problem is that sometime because of low-network connectivity, In My Application, Progress-Bar is keeps running for long time. I want to do some timeout period setting, so that if my application do not get any response in some particular time ( suppose 25 Secs. ) then Application should stop running.

How to set TimeOut value in J2ME Application, when I am using .net webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should start a `Thread` when starting the web service. This thread will then execute a `Timer`. Then when the delay expires then stop the app if response is null.

Comment: I do not want to code for the timeout. Coding for TimeOut would be my last option. First of all I want to find any readymade method if there is any.

Comment: yes , you are right, but i saw Timeout method in Android, So I thought it might possible in J2ME too.